Use $\,\varepsilon-\delta\,$ definition of limits to show that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(-1,2)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{7}{5}$
We need to show that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that
$$\left\lvert\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{7}{5}\right\rvert<\varepsilon $$
whenever
$$0<\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-2)^2}<\delta.$$
Consider
\begin{align*}\left\lvert\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{7}{5}\right\rvert
&=\left\lvert\frac{5(x^3+y^3)-7(x^2+y^2)}{5(x^2+y^2)}\right\rvert\\
&=\left\lvert\frac{x^2(5x-7)+y^2(5y-7)}{5(x^2+y^2)}\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant\left\lvert\frac{5x-7}{5}\right\rvert+\left\lvert\frac{5y-7}{5} \right\rvert
\end{align*}
From here I don't know how to use the inequality given for $\delta.$

You should manipulate the RHS in order to find something which goes to zero as $(x,y)\to (-1,2)$. For instance, starting from your work, we have
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{7}{5}\right\rvert&=\left\lvert\frac{5(x^3+y^3)-7(x^2+y^2)\color{red}{\pm 12}}{5(x^2+y^2)}\right\rvert\\
&=\left\lvert\frac{(x+1)(5x^2-12x+12)+(y-2)(5y^2+3y+6)}{5(x^2+y^2)}\right\rvert\\
&\leq \frac{|5x^2-12x+12|}{5(x^2+y^2)} |x+1|+
\frac{|5y^2+3y+6|}{5(x^2+y^2)} |y-2|
\end{align*}
Now $|x+1|<\delta$, $|y-2|<\delta$, and, assuming $\delta<1$, we also have that $0<|x|<2$, and $1<|y|<3$.
Can you take it from here and, given $\varepsilon >0$, find a suitable positive value for $\delta$ such that
$$\left\lvert\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{7}{5}\right\rvert<\varepsilon?$$

Alternative approach:
This approach presumes that the problem composer's intent is that $~\epsilon~$ and $~\delta~$ be wrestled with, rather than constructing an argument based on continuity of functions.  The required wrestling is do-able, with some tricks.
The point of these tricks will be to achieve a strictly linear relationship between $~\delta~$ and $~\epsilon.$

First of all, the premise that $~0 < | ~(\overline{x,y}) - (\overline{-1,2}) ~| < \delta $ implies that
$$|~x + 1~| < \delta ~~~\text{and} ~~~|~y - 2~| < \delta.$$
Further, for a variety of reasons, it will be helpful to introduce the artificial constraint that $~\delta \leq 1/100.~$
So, the premise of the problem has been transformed to:

$~\delta \leq 1/100.$

$-\delta - 1 < x < \delta - 1 \implies x < 0.$

$-\delta + 2 < y < \delta + 2 \implies y > 0.$

It is not the case that both of the following are true: 
$x = -1 ~$ and $~y = 2.$


At this point, the analysis can be simplified by only working with positive variables.
Let $~z = -x.~$
Then, you have that

$ 1 - \delta < z < 1 + \delta ~~~\text{and} ~~~z > 0.$


The goal is to demonstrate that a (linear) relationship between $~\delta~$ and $~\epsilon~$ can be established so that the premises (including the constraint that $~\delta \leq 1/100$) imply that
$$\left\lvert\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{7}{5}\right\rvert<\epsilon.  \tag1 $$
The desired conclusion in (1) above may be re-expressed as
$$-\epsilon + \frac{7}{5} < \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} < \epsilon + \frac{7}{5}. $$
Substituting the variable $~z~$ for the variable $~x,~$ the conclusion to be reached is
$$-\epsilon + \frac{7}{5} < \frac{-z^3+y^3}{z^2+y^2} < \epsilon + \frac{7}{5}. \tag2 $$

The next step is to establish upper and lower bounds on both of the expressions $~(-z^3 + y^3)~$ and $~(z^2 + y^2).$
You have that

$1 - \delta < z < 1 + \delta ~~~\text{and} ~~~z > 0.$

$\delta \leq 1/100 \implies 0 < 1 - \delta < 1 + \delta.~$


This implies that
$$(1 - \delta)^2 < z^2 < (1 + \delta)^2 \implies $$
$$1 - 2\delta + \delta^2 < z^2 < 1 + 2\delta + \delta^2.$$
Since $~\delta \leq 1/100,~$ you have that $~\delta^2 < \delta.$
Therefore, working in whole numbers, for simplicity,
$$1 - 2\delta < z^2 < 1 + 3\delta. $$
Similarly,
$$(1 - \delta)^3 < z^3 < (1 + \delta)^3 \implies $$
$$1 - 3\delta + 3\delta^2 - \delta^3 < z^3 < 1 + 3\delta + 3\delta^2 + \delta^3.$$
With $~\delta \leq \dfrac{1}{100},~$ this implies that
$$1 - 4\delta < z^3 < 1 + 4\delta.$$
This implies that
$$-4\delta - 1 < (-z)^3 < 4\delta - 1. $$

You have that

$-\delta + 2 < y < \delta + 2 + \delta ~~~\text{and} ~~~y > 0.$

$~\delta \leq 1/100 \implies 0 < -\delta + 2 < \delta + 2.~$


This implies that
$$(-\delta + 2)^2 < y^2 < (\delta + 2)^2 \implies $$
$$4 - 4\delta + \delta^2 < y^2 < 4 + 4\delta + \delta^2.$$
Again using that $~\delta^2 < \delta,~$ and working in whole numbers
$$4 - 4\delta < y^2 < 4 + 5\delta. $$
Similarly,
$$(-\delta + 2)^3 < y^3 < (\delta + 2)^3 \implies $$
$$8 - 12\delta + 6\delta^2 - \delta^3 < y^3 < 8 + 12\delta + 6\delta^2 + \delta^3.$$
Again using that $~\delta^3 < \delta^2 < \delta,~$ and working in whole numbers
$$8 - 13\delta < y^3 < 8 + 19\delta.$$

$\underline{\text{Summary of Analysis So Far}}$
Implied by the premises:

$0 < \delta \leq 1/100.$

$1 - 2\delta < z^2 < 1 + 3\delta.$

$-4\delta - 1 < (-z)^3 < 4\delta - 1.$

$4 - 4\delta < y^2 < 4 + 5\delta.$

$8 - 13\delta < y^3 < 8 + 19\delta.$


To Prove: 
A linear relationship between $~\delta~$ and $~\epsilon~$ may be established so that the following inequalities hold:
$$-\epsilon + \frac{7}{5} < \frac{-z^3+y^3}{z^2+y^2} < \epsilon + \frac{7}{5}. \tag3 $$
Let

$\displaystyle N~$ denote $~(-z^3 + y^3).$

$\displaystyle D~$ denote $~(z^2 + y^2).$


Then, the desired inequality in (3) above may be re-expressed as
$$-\epsilon + \frac{7}{5} < \frac{N}{D} < \epsilon + \frac{7}{5}. \tag4 $$
Further, you have that
$$7 - 17\delta < N < 7 + 23 \delta$$
and
$$5 - 6\delta < D < 5 + 8\delta.$$
A lower bound on $~\dfrac{N}{D}~$ may be established by considering a lower bound on $~N,~$ and an upper bound on $~D.$
Similarly, an upper bound on $~\dfrac{N}{D}~$ may be established by considering an upper bound on $~N,~$ and a lower bound on $~D.$
Therefore, you have that
$$\frac{7 - 17\delta}{5 + 8\delta} < \frac{N}{D} < \frac{7 + 23\delta}{5 - 6\delta}.$$
So, the entire problem reduces to establishing a linear relationship between $~\delta~$ and $~\epsilon~$ so that
$$-\epsilon + \frac{7}{5} < \frac{7 - 17\delta}{5 + 8\delta} < \frac{7 - 17\delta}{5}$$
and
$$\epsilon + \frac{7}{5} > \frac{7 + 23\delta}{5 - 6\delta} > \frac{7 + 23\delta}{5}.$$
The desired inequalities may be guaranteed by establishing that
$$\epsilon > \frac{17\delta}{5} ~~~\text{and} ~~~\epsilon > \frac{23\delta}{5}.$$
Therefore, the following specification works:
$$\delta = \min\left[ ~\frac{1}{100}, ~\frac{\epsilon}{5} ~\right].$$

To complement Robert Z's answer, here is a way that makes calculating the limit easier (albeit, it does not use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit directly.)
Note that the functions $x^{3}+y^{3}$ and $x^{2} + y^{2}$ are polynomials, and hence they are continuous everywhere. So the rational function $\dfrac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ is continuous wherever it is defined; in particular, wherever its denominator is nonzero.
Since the denominator is nonzero at $(x,y) = (-1,2)$, it's continuous there, and so its limit just equals its value:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(-1,2)} \dfrac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} = \dfrac{(-1)^{3}+2^{3}}{(-1)^{2}+2^{2}} = \dfrac{7}{5}.$$

Roblich, OP wants us to use the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition.

To emphasize the "not directly" aspect: the appropriate epsilon-delta version of the above would be to use that definition to prove that polynomials are continuous everywhere, and that ratios of continuous functions are continuous wherever the ratio is defined.

This was why I said it was to complement Robert Z's answer! I acknowledged in my answer that it does not (directly) use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits.
Though it does not directly answer the OP's answer as written, I think it adds valuable context to the problem at hand (especially since this is a question about limits, so it's probably from someone relatively new to the topic.) It relates the problem to polynomial limits, which they are likely more familiar with.
I hope this comment helps clarify my original answer! I hope I didn't come across as rude in my response! :)
